# Flask-PyMongo not working with Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pymongo

I need to use the import statement: `from flask_pymongo import PyMongo` with Python 2.7, but it gives the error: `ImportError: No module named flask_pymongo`

I even tried to install Flask-PyMongo using `pip install Flask-PyMongo`, it shows `Requirement already satisfied`. Attached is the screenshot of the same [Flask-PyMongo already present in Python2.7/dist-packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdqUP.png)

However if I run `from flask_pymongo import PyMongo` with Python3 then it doesn't give any error.

I need to run `from flask_pymongo import PyMongo` with Python2.7 instead of Python3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by:

- Check for the location where *flask_pymongo* is installed using the command: `sudo pip show flask_pymongo`. Result showed `Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
- Then check the packages which are in the python's default path using the commands: `import sys` `print (sys.path)`. Output showed `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
- Here was the problem: python2.7 was looking for packages in *dist-packages* whereas *flask_pymongo* was present in *site-packages*.
- To solve this, add the location to python's default path using `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`